How to know the number of rows displayed dynamically inside a flex wrap container?
There is a flex div having flex-wrap as wrap :

...
callAPI("/activites/prestationsFromGroupes", "POST", JSON.stringify(groupes)).then(prestationsGroupes => {
    let htmlPrestations = "";
    for(let i = 0 ; i < groupes.length ; i++) {
        let groupe = groupes[i];
        let prestations = prestationsGroupes[groupe['id']];
        let active = (i == onglet ? 'active' : '');
        htmlPrestations += '<div class="tab-pane min-h100 fade show '+active+'" id="pills-activites'+i+'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-activites'+i+'-tab">';
        htmlPrestations += '   <div class="group-menu-form">';
        for(let j = 0 ; j < prestations.length ; j++) {
            let prestation = prestations[j];
            let autoriseVae = prestation['autoriseVae'];
            let cuissonApplicable = prestation['cuissonApplicable'];
            let cdeCuisine = prestation['cdeCuisine'];
            let CSSbgcolor = prestation['couleur'] == "" ? "" : 'style="background-color: '+prestation['couleur']+';"';
            htmlPrestations += '   <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'+prestation['id']+'" data-libelle="'+prestation['libelle']+'" data-prix="'+nvl(prestation['prix'], 0)+'" data-prix-emporter="'+nvl(prestation['prixEmporter'], 0)+'" data-tva="'+nvl(prestation['tva'], 0)+'" data-autorisevae="'+autoriseVae+'" data-cuissonapplicable="'+cuissonApplicable+'" data-cdecuisine="'+cdeCuisine+'" title="'+prestation['libelle']+'">';
            htmlPrestations += '       <div class="menu-card" id="menu-card-'+prestation['id']+'" '+CSSbgcolor+'>';
            htmlPrestations += '           <div class="name-menu" id="prestalib_'+prestation['id']+'">'+prestation['libelle']+'</div>';
            htmlPrestations += '           <div class="group-menu">';
            htmlPrestations += '               <div class="price-menu" id="prestaprix_'+prestation['id']+'">';
            htmlPrestations += '                   '+prestation['prix']+" &euro;";
            htmlPrestations += '               </div>';
            htmlPrestations += '           </div>';
            htmlPrestations += '       </div>';
            htmlPrestations += '   </a>';
        }
        htmlPrestations += '   </div>';
        htmlPrestations += '</div>';
    }
    $("#pills-tabContent").html(htmlPrestations);
    ...

For example in the above photo there are 3 "rows" inside the div. So how to know that there are 3 "rows" ?

@pheromix... did you find the solution in the aforementioned answer given (that's exactly what you were looking for)? I mean given a container, the items to consider are just its children.. I'm confused reading this discussion going on
